# What is the reason for this error in jQuery/JavaScript function?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, validation

When I execute the following JavaScript function I receive the following error:

> '2' is null or not an object.

The input from `txtRawCardData` element is a string containing `^` character which I split into an string array.

**Update**

I receive this error only when I run my jQuery code in Internet Explorer 7.  I do not receive this error when I run it FireFox 3.5.6.

**Update 2:**

This error is also preventing any JavaScript functions I wrote for any ASP.NET `CustomValidator` controls from firing.

Sample Input:

> %B1234123412341234^JOHNSON/JOCKO^1234123412345700000000123000000?;1234123412341234=123443211234567?

```
function ProcessCCInfo() {
    var rawData = $('#txtRawCardData').val(); 
    rawData = rawData.replace('\n\r', '');                   
    var CCArray = rawData.split('^');

    //format the card holder name
    var NameArray = CCArray[1].split('/');
    var CCName = NameArray[1] + ' ' + NameArray[0];

    var CCNumber = CCArray[0].replace('%B', '');

    var CCExpiration = CCArray[2].substring(0,4) //this is the line generating the error!
    var FormattedDate = CCExpiration.substring(2,4) + '/' + CCExpiration.substring(0,2);

    $('#spanCardHolderName').attr('innerHTML', CCName);
    $('#spanCCNumber').attr('innerHTML', CCNumber); 
    $('#spanCCExpirationDate').attr('innerHTML', FormattedDate);

    setTimeout("$('#txtCustomerId').focus()", 1000);
}
```

Anyone know why it threw this error?

Comment: I assume you've verified that CCArray[2] is not null or empty?

Comment: @Nathan Taylor - `CCArray[2]` is does contain a value because it is populating the `CCExpiration` variable

Comment: @Michael Can you show an example of input it dies on (obviously with fake card data)? Can you try that input in the function that I put in my answer, and tell me if you still have problems?

Comment: @Brian - I provided an example of sample track data.  Also, it throw the error with any line of code dealing with accessing a array position in `CCArray` variable

Comment: @Michael Hmm, odd. Let me make sure I understand you. The lines `var NameArray = ...`, `var CCNumber = ...`, and `var CCExpiration =` all throw errors? But `var CCName = ...` does not? And what browser are you running?

Comment: @Brian - When I comment out the original line that is causing the issue, it throws error the followng error `'1' is null or not an object` at the `var NameArray = CCArray[1].split('/');` line.  I am currently using IE 7

Comment: @Brian - The error does not stop the function from running.  It has completed its execution

Comment: Hmm. This sounds like a browser bug, or something elsewhere in your code that is doing something truly strange with some built-in prototype. Do you get any similar error in any other browsers? (Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera)?

Comment: I just tested my application in FireFox and it did not throw any of those errors.

Comment: My application does interface with a USB card swiper that is hooked up my machine.

Comment: What does does CCArray.length return? and does it help to change it to change var CCExpiration = CCArray[2].substring(0,4) to make it var CCExpiration = CCArray[2].substring(0,4); with the semi colon on the end

Comment: @Mark - The length of CCArray is 3.  My array positioning is correct in my code.

Comment: @Michael Kniskern figured that, and the semi-colon ";" on the end?  Sometimes it "helps" the parser in weird circumstances.

Comment: @Mark - I put in code to remove the semi-colon and question mark.  It still through the same error.

Comment: This may be way off base, but it seems something amiss here.  Try reordering the statements, make sure they all have a semi-colon on the end - like put the one in error right after the one that creates the array...just a thought.

Comment: @Mark - all of my code lines have semi-colons and I reordered the statements and still get the same error.

Comment: Is your javascript by chance in a <script> block or in a separate file?

Comment: @Mark - It is in a `<script>` block

Answer (score 0):

The following code works in the firebug console, probably your input value is wrong:

```
function readCard(){
    var rawData = '%B13241234134^first/last^201111'; 
    rawData = rawData.replace('\n\r', '');                   
    var CCArray = rawData.split('^');

    //format the card holder name
    var NameArray = CCArray[1].split('/');
    var CCName = NameArray[1] + ' ' + NameArray[0];

    var CCNumber = CCArray[0].replace('%B', '');

    var CCExpiration = CCArray[2].substring(0,4) 

return [CCName, CCNumber, CCExpiration]}

readCard()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you encounter a problem like this, try checking your assumptions. Print out (or `alert()`) some of the intermediate values, to make sure that they are what you think they are. Try cutting it down to a short example so you can test what kinds of inputs it works with.

Here's an example. I've extracted just the text processing from your function, in order to see if it works:

```
function test(rawData) {
    rawData = rawData.replace('\n\r', '');                   
    var CCArray = rawData.split('^');

    //format the card holder name
    var NameArray = CCArray[1].split('/');
    var CCName = NameArray[1] + ' ' + NameArray[0];

    var CCNumber = CCArray[0].replace('%B', '');

    var CCExpiration = CCArray[2].substring(0,4) //this is the line generating the error!
    var FormattedDate = CCExpiration.substring(2,4) + '/' + CCExpiration.substring(0,2); 

    return CCName + " " + CCNumber + " " + CCExpiration + " " + FormattedDate;
}
```

Now, in Firebug or the WebKit inspector or Spidermonkey or the IE 8 JavaScript debugger or any other JavaScript read-eval-print loop you can find, you can try this function out, and test it with different inputs:

```
> test("12345^Last/First^0102")
"First Last 12345 0102 02/01"
> test("12345^Last/First")
TypeError: Result of expression 'CCArray[2]' [undefined] is not an object.
```

So, I would guess that you were passing in some kind of string that doesn't have two `^` characters in it. Stick an `alert(rawData)` right after you fetch it out of the element, and  then a `alert(CCArray)` right before the line where you get the error, and it will let you see what the values are, which could help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: @Brian - I modified my code and the local variables with the CCArray values in the `attr` statements and they all contained values.

Answer (score 0):

remember that the `rawData = rawData.replace('\n\r', '');` will only replace the first '\n\r' it encounters and not all of them ...

to replace all use a regular expression with the global flag

```
rawData = rawData.replace(/(\r\n|[\r\n])/g, '');
```